# 100% CPU usage after npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I have Node.js locally on my machine with npm. When I start npm install no matter what I've install I get 100% CPU and RAM usage.Only reboot helps.

```
Node ver. 8.11.1  

npm ver. 5.6.0

OS Win 7.
```

How can I find the problem? I used only npm and did not do any manipulations to packages or Node.js.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

PS I also have a MacOS, but there is no such a problem with the same project.
PC specs: i3-2100 3.1Ghz, 16Gb RAM.
Screens:
[CPU usage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQcER.jpg)
[Processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzTxB.jpg)

Comment: You mean that the installation process never ends and eats all resources? What's your OS?

Comment: No, installation process finishes but CPU/memory load remains 100%.
OS Win 7.
PS I also have a MacOS, but there is no such a problem with the same project.

Comment: We'll need your package.json file in order to figure something out. Otherwise it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Are you trying first time on Win? Can you please add Hardware specification of Win? If you don't mind. Can you add a screenshot of CPU usage too? May these kind of information help to identify issue.

Comment: @Neekoy I updated the answer, at package.json you can find only standart dependencies for React app, from this starter template:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: @Hardik Shah I've added scrennshots and PC specs, sorry but it in Russian, but I think everything is clear. I get the issue some time ago, I can not associate it with anything and what could be the cause of that.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: @Parth Patel - nope, I think it is some specific windows issue.MacOS does not have any problems.

Comment: @IvanSpk - I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I noticed that whenever my NodeJS server encounters an error like not able to parse a null response from MongoDB through mongoose, even after closing the process by pressing control + c , the process became an orphan process and was keeping CPU busy at 100%. That's roughly my issue. Not an OS specfic issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using macOS, consider installing `fsevents`. See also this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/axa-ch/patterns-library/issues/1732